# How to call App object from inside of tests

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have an object that extends the App trait, and I want to write some tests that use this object. E.g.

```
object EntryPoint extends App {
  println("running the app")
  // runs misc code
}
```

I want to write something like:

```
class EntrySpec extents FlatSpec {
  val entryPoint = EntryPoint(Array("Some arg"))
  // do stuff with the entrypoint object
}
```

But when I try to do this, I cant seem to access the EntryPoint object in my test. All other objects and classes resolve normally. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write with `.main(..)` in `EntrySpec`

*/src/main/scala/EntryPoint.scala*

```
object EntryPoint extends App {
  println(s"running the app, args=${args.mkString}")
}
```

*/src/test/scala/EntrySpec.scala*

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

class EntrySpec extends FlatSpec {
  EntryPoint.main(Array("Some arg")) // prints "running the app, args=Some arg"

  assert(1 + 1 === 2)
}
```

Everything should work.